# Android 6 Marshmallow Black Screen after set Permission to Never Ask Again

Tags: android, permissions, screen, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have got this really weird behaviour.

After adding the permissions at runtime for my app, I was checking and testing all cases.

I have the request code in my MainActivity.

So, after I set Never Ask Again and deny the giving permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, if I press the menu button and then restart the app (the app will call onResume of MainActivity I guess), then the screen is black except a rectangle part in the middle of the screen which varies in size. (Is not the AlertDialog size)

Here some screenshots:

Normal screen

[image: Normal]

After press menu and then open again can be that it opens with the normal state or with these states:

[image: black screen with random size square visible]

Or

[image: smaller square]

This is quite weird, anybody had this before?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, it's hard to give a very accurate answer.

When requesting permissions, if the user selected 'never ask again', the request permissions response will be denied.  I'm GUESSING (due to lack of code) that your app relies on the granted permission to continue loading the UI and executing more code, which it won't do if permission is denied.  You need to handle all possible responses when requesting runtime permissions.

if permission is granted: good to go
if permission is denied: check if you should show the permission rationale.  This means you display a message to the user explaining why you need the permission.

if shouldShowRationale is true:  it means 'never ask again' was NOT checked.  Display the message, then ask for permission again.

if should show Rationale is false: it means 'never ask again' was checked and you should probably direct the user to the app settings to turn the permission on if it's required.